# redundant results are saved when using Export-CSV

Tags: powershell, log4j

I have a working script for detecting Log4j but trying to export all the result to CSV.

The current script was able to export but is giving me multiple rows of exact result.

```
$hostnames = "PC1"
foreach ($hostname in $hostnames){

Write-Host "Starting..."

$List = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname  {Get-ChildItem 'C:\' -Recurse -Force -Include *.jar -ea 0 | foreach {select-string "JndiLookup.class" $_} | select -exp Path}
            
if ($List -ne $null) 
{
    $List1 = [system.String]::Join("`r`n", $List)

    $file_location = "C:\Powershell\log4j-test.csv"
    
    $global:name = @{N="Computer Name";E={$hostname}}
    $global:lists = @{N="Affected Location";E={$List1}}
    
    Write-Host "Done.."

    $name, $lists | Export-CSV $file_location -noTypeInformation -Force -Append -Encoding UTF8
    
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show an example of these duplicate rows? As far as I can tell, your script is going to output a bunch of garbage information about hashtables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  'Computer Name' = $hostname
  'Affected Location' = $List -join "`r`n"
} | Export-CSV $file_location -noTypeInformation -Force -Append -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that each single CSV row created in each iteration will (potentially) *span multiple lines*, due to using newlines (`` "`r`n" ``) as separators in the `Affected Location` column.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your hashtable literals (e.g. `@{N="Computer Name";E={$hostname}}`) use the syntax of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), yet you're not using a cmdlet - typically [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) - that is capable of creating calculated properties.
- More generally, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) in *Windows PowerShell* do *not* meaningfully support [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) as input objects - you'll need to provide `[pscustomobject]` instances instead, which you can easily create by casting<sup>[1]</sup>  a hashtable literal to `[pscustomobject]`, as shown above

  - By contrast, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you may now use hashtables directly as input, though you'll probably want to use `[ordered]` hashtables for predictable column ordering.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, the form `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` isn't a *cast*, but *built-in syntactic sugar* for creating `[pscustomobject]` instances as literals. This is evidenced by the fact that the key-definition order in the hashtable literal is *maintained* in this case, whereas it isn't in stand-alone hashtable literals.</sup>